# Can I leave my home's water shut off overnight without damaging the heaters?

Tags: plumbing, heating

We were trying to do a job ourselves and don't have what we need to finish installing a new vanity in the bathroom.  Shut the water off to install new sink and now can't turn it back on because we don't have what we need to connect the line to the sink correctly.  Are we ok to leave the main water line shut off overnight or is this going to mess with the hot water or gas heating systems?  help!

Comment: is there is no shutoff below the sink? ..... why don't you reinstall the old tap?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned gas I would turn the water heater to pilot. Turning the water heater to pilot will keep it from running and when you are ready turn it back to the temp you want. I think it may be fine just over night to leave it on but why take a chance.